# Ubuntu 24.04 Container generating excessive logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs

I am building a workflow that uses containers and Cloud Batch.
My current container is created from a Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV CONTAINER_NAME="python3"
RUN apt-get update && \  
...
```

I have used this container successfully in Google and Azure Batch with no issues.

I recently rebuilt the container using:

```
FROM ubuntu:24.04
ENV CONTAINER_NAME="python3"
RUN apt-get update && \  
...
```

Nothing else changed in my Docker file or workflow. Running the same Cloud Batch program using the the 24.04 container created an excessive amount of logging. CPU costs went up ~25% because of the logs being captured by Cloud Logging and Cloud Logging costs are excessive.

Nothing in my workflow is specifically impacting Cloud Logging, so this activity must be coming from the base Container configuration. My theory is basic logging in 22.02 is set to a certain level (Info) and in 24.04 it is set to the equivalent of Debug. If I want to use 24.04, I need to configure logging in 24.04 to be similar to 22.04.

What linux commands can I use to:

1. check how logging is done in these containers
2. check the settings/configuration related to logging
3. change the settings/configuration related to logging

Comment: There could be a few settings to manage logs, but... First of all have you understood why is this happening?

does "docker container logs -f container_name" show something being spammed in the logs?